# WordPress - wp_schedule_event run between two times

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cron

I am running my custom script via WP Cron.

```
/**
 * Plugin activation function
 */
function mcsPEventsActivation()
{
    // Schedule cron
    if (! wp_next_scheduled('mcs_populate_cron_hook')) {
        // Log cron job hook
        if (function_exists('mcsWriteLog')) {
            mcsWriteLog('mcs_populate_cron_hook cron job starting now');
        }
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'ten_minutes', 'mcs_populate_cron_hook');
    }
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'mcsPEventsActivation');
// Add custom action to execute code.
add_action("mcs_populate_cron_hook", "mcsPopulateScrappedData", 12);
```

I have "recurrence" parameter set to custom schedule i.e., "ten_minutes."

I know I can run this schedule job on a specific time by setting "timestamp" parameter but I want this schedule job only to run durin' 6:00 a.m. to 8:00 a.m.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your task, you can change your cron schedule action that you registered in plugin activation hook. Its fire once at the time of plugin activation only. You can do as follows, its check on every load with your specific time interval and schedule the cron event -

```
/**
 * Plugin Init function
 */
function mcsPEventsActivation()
{
    $now = new DateTime();
    $begin = new DateTime('6:00');
    $end = new DateTime('8:00');

    if ($now >= $begin && $now <= $end){
        // Schedule cron
        if (! wp_next_scheduled('mcs_populate_cron_hook')) {
            // Log cron job hook
            if (function_exists('mcsWriteLog')) {
                mcsWriteLog('mcs_populate_cron_hook cron job starting now');
            }
            wp_schedule_event(time(), 'ten_minutes', 'mcs_populate_cron_hook');
        }
    } else {
        if (wp_next_scheduled('mcs_populate_cron_hook')) {
            $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled( 'mcs_populate_cron_hook' );
            wp_unschedule_event( $timestamp, 'mcs_populate_cron_hook' );
            wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'mcs_populate_cron_hook' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'mcsPEventsActivation', 99 );
```